# Вызов родительского метода из дочернего класса

Tags: c++, ооп, функции, классы

есть класс
customclass.h

```
class CustomClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CustomClass();
    int step = 0;
    virtual void doStep();
};
```

в cpp в методе doStep прибавляем на единицу переменную step
дочерний класс:

```
class ChildClass : public CustomClass
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ChildClass();
    int childSome;
    void doStep() override;
};
```

cpp:

```
#include "customclass.h"
ChildClass::ChildClass() {
}

void ChildClass::doStep(){
    **как тут вызвать метод doStep родительского класса**
    childSome++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Так и вызвать -

```
CustomClass::doStep();
```

Если очень хочется - можно написать

```
this->CustomClass::doStep();
```

но это не обязательно :)